# In an RDLC consume white space when hiding an image based on an expression

Tags: rdlc

I have an RDLC that has an image in it that gets its image to be shown from a database.

I have set the visibility to show the image based on a true/false expression.

My problem is, when the image gets hidden, the white space is not consumed and there is a big gap between elements.

Other elements like rectangles that get hidden consume the white space appropriately, but not the image.  Is there something special I need or can do to have an image element consume white space as well?